# Multiple monitors, different resolutions break maximize button

Tags: 11.04, unity, multiple-monitors, display

After installing 11.04 I noticed that the maximize button is broken with multiple monitors at a different resolution. When clicking on maximize on the screen with the lowest resolution, the titlebar of the application gets hidden under the top-panel and the application is resized to half of the screen.

This is an *extremely* annoying issue.

Before Maximizing:

[image: Before maximizing]

After Maximizing:
[image: After maximizing]

Comment: Better as a bug report? Please file one in LaunchPad.